# What is a word that means "lacking seriousness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an essay for *In Our Time* by Ernest Hemingway and I need a word that means "to lack seriousness".

Comment: Have you looked up antonyms of _serious_?

Comment: Immature comes to mind as a possibility.

Comment: In honor of Hemingway's boxing, your could say "lightweight".

Answer (score 11):

"Frivolous" maybe?

I think it depends on what you consider as seriousness, like "depth" or serious mood.

Google translate also yields

> flippant, glib, facetious, joking, jokey, lighthearted, fatuous, inane, senseless, thoughtless, flip; time-wasting, pointless, trivial, trifling, minor, petty, insignificant, unimportant, de minimis

Answer (score 5):

**flippant** - (adj) "lacking proper respect or seriousness" - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flippant), frivolously disrespectful or lacking in seriousness. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flippant)

> - "He made a flippant response to a serious question."
> - "His flippant comment offended many people."
> - "You have many talents but you are a flippant person."

Answer (score 2):

***is silly*** seems simple. The thesaurus yields wonders from there.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, **Levity**:

> Google response for **lev·i·ty** /ˈlevədē/ (noun): levity; (plural noun: levities) humor or frivolity, especially the treatment of a serious matter with humor or in a manner lacking due respect. i.e., "as an attempt to introduce a note of *levity*, the words were a disastrous flop"
>
> **synonyms**: lightheartedness, high spirits, vivacity, liveliness, cheerfulness, cheeriness, humor, gaiety, fun, jocularity, hilarity, frivolity, amusement, mirth, laughter, merriment, glee, comedy, wit, wittiness, jollity, joviality, i.e., "without some occasional *levity*, the working environment is no better than a sweatshop"

Answer (score 0):

Insincere.

Also maybe Trivial or, depending on context, I also like Flip or Flippant (previously suggested by @Centaurus.)